# Why is this character sitting in the iron throne at the end of S06E10

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of the TV episode *The Winds of Winter*, we see

> Cersei sitting and crowned on the iron throne.

What makes them sit there given that

> She isn't a Baratheon. Remaining Baratheons, by blood, should then have priority, even if all Robert's, Stannis' and Renly's lines are cut. Cousins probably?
>  She isn't male, while the series told us for years that women don't sit in that throne (books might say otherwise, though). Season 6 changed that, but there were several hints through the series that this is true. Jaime would be fitting better on the throne than Cersei. It seems to me that in the sexist world of Westerns, they'd better forgive a man some promise rather than let a woman take the lead. See Jon / Sansa in the very same episode.
>  Even though she killed her accusers, the rumours and reasons why her trial had to take place haven't disappeared with the High Sparrow.
>  Some people can still see her game. She has The Mountain to fix that but he only stops individuals, not the entire system, doesn't he?
>
>  At best she'd be a regent, not a queen...

Comment: Help fixing the spoiler tags please? I just can't set them straight :/ Also, I posted from the phone, so sorry for the bad quality.

Comment: I spoilered what you wanted spoilered. For some reason you need to put a `>!` at the start of blank lines between paragraphs too.

Comment: Also, *The Winds of Winter* =/= GoT season 6.

Comment: @Theyna Yep, it's a duplicate. Still a good question though, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the tags! The name of the episode is *The Winds of Winter*.

Comment: IMHO - No reason except poor writing.

Comment: " while the series told us for years that women don't sit in that throne" There is a difference in saying that no woman has sat on that throne, and saying that women are inherently incapable of sitting on that throne. If I'm not mistaken, Westerosi inheritance favors the men (the oldest first), but then moves on to the women (again the oldest first). For the same reason, Sansa is considered the Lady of Winterfell as there are no male heirs (known to be alive), and Jon is not a Stark. (His position as da king in da norf is not based on him being a Stark, but because people united behind him)